# Here is a simple code I am trying to run on Jupyter and this came

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```py
list=[12,15,18,21,26]
for i in list:
    if list % 5 == 0:
        print(list)
        break


Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-dbdee19fa7cd> in <module>
      1 list=[12,15,18,21,26]
      2 for i in list:
----> 3     if list % 5 == 0:
      4         print(list)
      5         break

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: Beween which two entities are you using the % operator?

Comment: Use [...] `if i % 5 == 0:` [...].

Comment: please don't use `list` as a variable name in python

Answer (score 0):

You iterated through list with `i` but then used list instead, which is incompatible. Try:

```
if i % 5 == 0
```

Also, I would recommend renaming list to something else.

Comment: If this helped, Please upvote and mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `i % 5` instead of `list % 5`

```py
list1 = [12,15,18,21,26] 
for i in list1: 
    if i % 5 == 0: 
        print(i) 
        break
```